# Qual a origem da expressão "Macacos me mordam"?

Tags: significado, etimologia, expressões

Qual seria o sentido de utilizar essa expressão? Não penso que tenha surgido por alguma mordida real de um macaco em um ser humano, mas fiquei curioso para saber de onde veio.
É uma expressão que geralmente ouvimos em filmes, mas sinceramente nunca pensei bem sobre o que significa.
Gostaria realmente de saber a origem, e qual seu real significado.

Comment: Se alguém editar a pergunta solicito ser avisado para que eu veja se há necessidade de modificar a resposta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Macacos me mordam*** (se qualquer coisa) é uma de várias fórmulas similares que aparecem na literatura a partir de meados do século XIX, e que o locutor usa para assegurar a sua sinceridade, convicção e seriedade. O primeiro exemplo que encontrei é de 1860: o autor afirma que não entende nada “destas cousas”, e invoca sobre si o mal de ser mordido por macacos se são estiver a ser sincero (o uso do *nem* é estranho para padrões modernos):

> macacos me mordam, se entendo destas cousas nem pitada
>   [“Dous Leigos ás Reverencias” em *Bem Público* (periódico português) nº 11, 15-9-1860.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=zpdYl0x6jVsC&pg=PA86&dq=%22macacos%20me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnlKiPrKTVAhXIAxoKHWnyAEA4lgEQ6AEIhwEwEA#v=onepage&q=%22macacos%20me%22&f=false)

Curiosamente, num curto período, entre 1848 e 1863, aparecem na literatura várias expressões deste tipo. Indico as mais antigas de cada tipo que encontrei no Google Books:

> As cobras me comão, se eu o entendo a você!
>   [Alfredo P. Hogan, *Mysterios de Lisboa*, Lisboa, 1851.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=MEETAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA43&dq=%22me%20com%C3%A3o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNqt-0_5rVAhXGWRQKHX8_D_QQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22me%20com%C3%A3o%22&f=false)
>
> Gatos me lambam se entendo esta embrulhada.
>   [Luiz Miguel Quadros, *O Sogro da Rapasiada,* (teatro) Maranhão, 1861.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=WMRXAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA36&dq=%22me%20lambam%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0i8yg_ZrVAhWBshQKHbCHCrM4MhDoAQj-ATAj#v=onepage&q=%22me%20lambam%22&f=false)
>
> Lobos me comam, resmungou entre dentes, se aquillo não foi mau olhado que lhe deitaram.
>   [Augusto Sarmento, *Providencia*, Coimbra, 1863.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=oBBZ0IorF3sC&pg=PA36&dq=%22me%20comam%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwic7r7fw6LVAhWBuBQKHZ3lCpY4lgEQ6AEIygEwGg#v=onepage&q=%22me%20comam%22&f=false)
>
> Mil boccas de fogo me comam se eu entendo hoje o meu capitão !
>   [José Romano, *29 ou Honra e Gloria* (teatro), Lisboa, 1858, p. 29.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=oJruAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA39&dq=%22me%20comam%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiaqY2GgpvVAhVDWxQKHWKDDLc4-gEQ6AEIoAEwDw#v=onepage&q=%22me%20comam%22&f=false)
>
> Talvez… mas tantas balas me matem, se eu dava mais de quatrocentos mil réis por tudo…
>   [(Idem, p. 46.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=oJruAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA46&dq=%22balas%20me%20matem%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-_8Pb-aTVAhXCWxoKHTMRDnUQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22balas%20me%20matem%22&f=false)
>
> Terçans [febre que se repete a cada três dias [(Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/ter%C3%A7%C3%A3)] me comam, se te entendo, homem!
>   [Alexandre Herculano, *O Monge de Cister*, original de 1848.](https://archive.org/stream/omongedecistro00herc#page/160/mode/2up)
>
> Mil raios me partam se eu o entendo a você…
>   [“Romance. Criminosa ou Infeliz?” em *Revista Popular*, n.º 28, 1848.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=aJs9AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA219&dq=%22raios%20me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQtcW-y6LVAhXDuhQKHQETDIYQ6AEIXzAI#v=onepage&q=%22raios%20me%22&f=false)
>
> Má diabos me matem s’eu lhe disser que nan…
>   [Aristides Abranches, *Mariquinhas, a Leiteira*, (teatro), Lisboa, 1855.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=tL9XAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA6&dq=%22me%20matem%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi35-uUnaTVAhXCzxQKHfjzBgQ4rAIQ6AEISzAF#v=onepage&q=%22me%20matem%22&f=false)

Com o passar do tempo vão aparecendo mais variantes: *macacos me comam* [(Inglês de Sousa, 1891)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Y7FOAQAAIAAJ&q=%22me%20comam%22&dq=%22me%20coma%20m%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwic7r7fw6LVAhWBuBQKHZ3lCpY4lgEQ6AEIogEwFA), *macacos me lambam* [(*Almanaque Brasileiro*, 1912)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Ma1LAQAAIAAJ&q=%22me%20lambam%22&dq=%22me%20lambam%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3ye3XvKLVAhXM6RQKHcqTDYE4MhDoAQjrATAg); *tubarões me comam* [*Gazeta das Aldeias*, 1907)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Mwo-AQAAMAAJ&q=%22me%20comam%22&dq=%22me%20comam%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOysXmx6LVAhXGVxQKHbDQDdw4ZBDoAQjOAjAu); *um boi me lamba* [Martins d’Alvarez, 1937)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=TLbuAAAAMAAJ&q=%22me%20lamba%22&dq=%22me%20lamba%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC7cm066LVAhVMVhQKHek6AeI4MhDoAQixAjAu).

Disto tudo, creio que *macacos me mordam* se tornou a fórmula mais popular. Era a única que eu conhecia, para além de *raios me partam*, claro. Atualmente é usada também como interjeição, exprimindo surpresa, perplexidade, ou simplesmente para libertar tensão.

Todas estas fórmulas são elaborações de uma mais antiga, simplesmente ***que me matem***, que encontramos já no século XVI:

> Oo, que me matẽ se não he minha prima Francina
>   [Jorge Ferreira de Vasconcelos, *Comédia Eufrosina,* 1560.](http://purl.pt/12154/6/#/135)
>
> Que me matem se não saõ estes os Chenchicogis
>   [Fernão Mendes Pinto, *Peregrinação,* Lisboa 1614.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=JcbeQEHDX-wC&pg=PA158-IA1&dq=%22que%20me%20matem%20fe%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8-f_Mp6TVAhVBthQKHT8yA8IQ6AEIUDAG#v=onepage&q=%22que%20me%20matem%20fe%22&f=false)
>
> Ora que me matem, se mo nam levou aquelle ladravaz de Montalvão
>   [António Ferreira, “Comedia de Bristo”, Acto III, Scena V em Francisco de Saa de Mirãnda & Antonio Ferreira, *Comedias Famosas Portuguesas*, Lisboa, 1622.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Fi0ifeuV6xoC&pg=PA96-IA1&dq=%22me%20matem%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi35-uUnaTVAhXCzxQKHfjzBgQ4rAIQ6AEIwQIwJQ#v=onepage&q=%22me%20matem%22&f=false)

Parece-me que *macacos me mordam* e muitas das variantes modernas resultam simplesmente da imaginação e até da veia cómica popular. Para quem levasse a sério juras deste tipo, só os raios, diabos e as terçãs representam um mal que se pudesse verosimilmente invocar. *Gatos me lambam* é para rir. Em Portugal não há macacos nem cobras que possam comer uma pessoa. Mesmo no Brasil, parece-me que no passado uma pessoa correria muito mais risco de apanhar uma dentada dum cão, um coice duma mula ou uma cornada dum boi que uma dentada dum macaco. Mesmo indo para o mato, maior perigo viria das onças, cobras e aranhas venenosas ou até de índios hostis.

Já diabos, para quem acredita, raios e terçãs, podem atingir uma pessoa em qualquer lado e a qualquer hora. E destes males todos, são precisamente os diabos, raios e terçãs que são ou foram no passado usados para rogar pragas. *Raios te partam* vem já [neste dicionário de 1842](https://books.google.pt/books?id=IwcoAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA326&dq=%22raios%20te%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiboIug2qLVAhUHuBQKHSTgARw4yAEQ6AEIrQEwFA#v=onepage&q=%22raios%20te%22&f=false). *Terçãs* eu nem sabia o que era, mas encontramo-la em pragas, como “terçãs te comam, demónio” [(Alexandre Herculano, 1848)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ikJEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA290&dq=%22ter%C3%A7ans%20te%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj1qmYiaTVAhXJVhQKHS6MBN0Q6AEIbTAK#v=onepage&q=%22ter%C3%A7ans%20te%22&f=false) e “más terçans te limpem, coruja” [(Camilo Castelo-Branco, 1849)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=1LI4AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA17&dq=%22ter%C3%A7ans%20te%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj1qmYiaTVAhXJVhQKHS6MBN0Q6AEIZTAJ#v=onepage&q=%22ter%C3%A7ans%20te%22&f=false).

Mas não estou a ver ninguém dizer com raiva, “macacos te mordam, canalha”, nem encontrei nenhuma imprecação desse tipo. Portanto parece-me que do singelo *que me matem* o pessoal foi simplesmente inventando fórmulas mais elaboradas, recorrendo a palavras usadas em pragas nuns casos e à imaginação e veia cómica noutros.

Comment: A expressão "[substantivo] me morda(m)" era bastante usado pelo personagem Popeye, assim como a expressão "por mil demônios", só que quase sempre ele usava isso como uma interjeição de surpresa/espanto ou perturbação. Esse uso também seria legítimo? (Um exemplo de episódio onde ele usa essa expressão seria [este](https://youtu.be/45krbpJd8Wg?t=1m1s), em que ele usa "tubarões me mordam".)

Comment: @Bruno, vi o episódio, e o "tubarões me mordam" soou-me perfeitamente natural. Pelo menos aqui em Portugal é comum usar *macacos me mordam* para exprimir perplexidade, como eu já observo na resposta. O "tubarões" foi possivelmente um ajustamento ao contexto--o Popeye é marinheiro; imagino que tenha sido isso também no exemplo "tubarões me comam" da resposta--a cena passa-se num barco. No fundo o uso interjetivo para exprimir espanto, perplexidade, deve ter nascido da truncagem da fórmula classica: *macacos me mordam! (se eu entendo isto)*; >>

Comment: >>  *Macacos me mordam se não é a prima Francina* = *Macacos me mordam! É a prima Francina*; etc.

Comment: O interessante pra mim é o subjuntivo "velado",

Comment: @Lambie, "velado"?! Para mim é um subjuntivo normalíssimo, segundo o modelo de *Deus te **abençoe**, o Diabo **seja** cego, surdo e mudo*, ["O dia em que nasci moura e pereça, / Não o **queira** jamais o tempo dar; / Não **torne** mais ao Mundo", etc.](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~cfb/VdS/v057.txt).

Comment: Jacinto, velado no sentido de que não aparece o "que": Que Deus me abençoe. Sería algo como "Que marcacos me mordam se [não-sei-o-que]".  Queria dizer o "que" é velado.

Comment: @Lambie, ah, isso. O "que" não é necessário. Podes dizer "que Deus te abençoe", mas é mais comum sem o "que". E se inverteres o verbo-sujeito não pões mesmo o "que": *benza-te Deus, salve-se quem puder, vão-se os anéis e que fiquem os dedos*. Quer dizer, podes dizer *que se vão os anéis*..., mas o normal é sem o *que*.

Comment: Não tenho certeza disso. Depende de onde na frase se coloca.  Alguns dos exemplos que você acaba de dar acabam sendo frases soltas ou em casos como Não torne mais ao Mundo, não me parece subjuntivo, é imperativo. Mas deixemos o assunto. :)

Comment: @Lambie, não tens tu a certeza, mas tenho eu. Sim, o *que* e desnecessário em certo tipo de frases, não em todas. Não importa se a frase é solta. O que interessa é que seja completa (aqui não posso tirar o *que* do *que seja*), e todas as minhas são  completas, com sujeito e verbo.  No soneto do Camões (não torne mais ao mundo, etc.) é subjuntivo, exprimindo um desejo; não estás a ordenar ao mundo que não queira, ou ao dia que não torne; para isso precisavas de um pronome de tratamento (Dia, você/o senhor não torne...), senão seria *não tornes* ou *não torneis*.

Comment: @Jacinto Falei que não tinha certeza. E não estou falando de Camões há 500 anos atrás. Estou falando da fala moderna. // Que não torne mais ao mundo se refere a qué? O poeta está invocando alguém ou não? tornar é voltar, né? Se eu falar: Que não tome mais cafe? Existe também o sujeito nulo ...

Answer (score 6):

Respondo a uma de suas perguntas: "qual o sentido de usar essa expressão?". Bem, o sentido é querer convencer alguém de que você está tão certo a respeito de alguma coisa a ponto de desejar algo ruim a si próprio caso aquilo não ocorra ou não seja verdade.

Exemplos:

- Quero que um raio caia na minha cabeça se isso não for verdade.
- Macacos me mordam se ela não aceitar a oferta.
- Quero ser mico de circo se ele não está mentindo.
- Eu vendo minha alma ao diabo se eu não conseguir.

Answer (score -4):

O usuário Fabrício Vaz, no [Yahoo Respostas](http://web.archive.org/web/20201029053357/https://br.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080110055328AAhicVh), afirma o seguinte:

> "Na verdade, a primeira aparição dessa expressão que se tem notícia, foi na guerra do Paraguai, utilizada pelo Conde D'Eu.
> Os soldados negros (escravos) da tropa brasileira eram conhecidos como macacos e estavam insurgindo contra o comandante que os utilizavam na linha de frente no combate como bois de piranha. Então para incentiva-los em algum plano, dizia: "macacos me mordam se eu não vencer Solano Lopez!"."

Comment: Aqui está um exemplo mais antigo, de 1860, quatro anos antes de começar a guerra do Paraguai: ["macacos me mordam, se entendo destas cousas nem pitada](https://books.google.pt/books?id=zpdYl0x6jVsC&pg=PA86&dq=%22macacos+me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFrYvE9prVAhVJvBQKHZvWDck4lgEQ6AEIgQEwDw#v=onepage&q=%22macacos%20me%22&f=false).

Comment: Creio que os escravos que sentavam praça na Guerra do Paraguai eram automaticamente alforriados.

Comment: Fico curioso de saber qual a razão de dois votos negativos. A pergunta inicial não mostrou nenhuma pesquisa nem esforço de procurar uma resposta antes de postar. Por outro lado @Centaurus nem respondeu a pergunta da origem, e ganhou 3 votos positivos. Achei curioso, só.

Comment: Ian, eu não votei nesta pergunta, nem para baixo nem para cima. Não posso explicar os votos dos outros, mas também não vejo mérito na resposta. O usuário que citas não é, que nós saibamos, nenhuma autoridade na matéria, e não apresenta qualquer fonte que nos permita confirmar o que ele afirma. Quando se apresenta "uma primeira" ocorrência de uma expressão, é conveniente apresentar prova que ela é genuína.

Comment: @Ian Usando o Yahoo Respostas como fonte, fica meio complicado alguém confiar na sua resposta...